# Is it possible to deploy my Node.js project on AWS EC2 using two separate self-hosted GitHub actions for main and staging branches?

Tags: node.js, github, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I have a github repository for nodejs project. I am deploying my project into aws ec2 through github action. Now i have two branches main and staging. I want to run two seperate self-hosted action according to the branches. How can i achieve this?

Thank You

I tried creating 2 actions runner but only one works whenever i push code into main branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 separate workflow files and configure push branch trigger like below

---

- For main

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
       - <BRANCH>
....
```

---

- For stage

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
       - <BRANCH>
....
```

---

**Note: If you have same branch to deploy both environment you can set same branch in both workflow file.**

Comment: Sure this will create two separate push handlers. But how to define in SelfHosted runner to identify which one is for whom. Like main branch for runner 1 and staging for runner 2

Comment: for that, you have to set `runs-on: self-hosted` in your workflow file.

Comment: you can set `runs-on: runner-1` for your main workflow and `runs-on: runner-2` for stage workflow.